# How to add jar file to every new project automatically on eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

I have a jar file and I want that whenever I create a new project in Eclipse it will be added to it automatically, is there a way to do it? 
I tried to add it by adding a new jar file into a project, but it adds it only to one project and when I create a new one it doesn't contain the jar file.

Comment: You can add the JAR to an JRE/JDK which can be used for new projects: In _Window > Preferences: Java > Installed JARs_ you can specify your own JRE/JDK with additional JARs (in the dialog to add or to edit an JRE there is an _Add External JARs..._ button).

Comment: @howlger Thank you very much!